# Поиск по RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня стоит задача отфильтровать слова по поиску в RecyclerView, я написал метод, но он не работает.

```
class WordsFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_words, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    etSearchBar.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            Log.e("1", "Он должен был увидеть " + s)
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            updateSearch() // эта строчка не работает Cannot find decloration to go to
        }

    })


    val repository: WordsRepository =
        WordsRepositoryImpl(WordsDatabaseDataSourceImpl(context!!))

    val items = repository.getAllWords()

    val myAdapter = MainAdapter(items, object : MainAdapter.Callback {
        override fun onItemClicked(item: Word) {
            //TODO Сюда придёт элемент, по которому кликнули. Можно дальше с ним работать
        }
    })
    myRecycler.adapter = myAdapter

    fun updateSearch(s:String) {
        if(s?.length == 0){
            myAdapter.items = repository.getAllWords() // Вывод всего списка, если EditText пустой
        } else {
            myAdapter.items = repository.findWords(String()) // Вывод отфильтрованного списка (фильтрацию я описал в другом классе в SQL)
        }
    }
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // Обновление адаптера
}
}
```

Я не пойму, в чем ошибка, все делал по [уроку](https://medium.com/@dracveg/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-recyclerview-fca7653f8e45), но updateSearch все равно не работает. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Буду очень благодарен. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Функция updateSearch принимает один аргумент. Ты же его не посылаешь, вот и получаешь cannot find declaration to go.

Вообще ты в целом можешь подключить фильтр к адаптеру. В общих чертах делает это примерно так:

```
    //твой класс адаптера
    private val filter: Filter

    init {
       filter = attachFilter()
    }


    private fun attachFilter() = object : Filter() {
    override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): FilterResults 
      {
        val filteredList: MutableList<Items  (string/int/твой класс)> = ArrayList()
        if (charSequence.isEmpty()) {
            filteredList.addAll(mItemList)
        } else {
            //mItemList - список всех твоих элементов
            //рекомендую сделать его копию, чтобы потом, в случаях если строка для поиска пустая
            //можно было просто восстановить первоначальные элементы
            filteredList.addAll(mItemList.filter { currentItem ->
                currentItem.contains(charSequence, true)
            })
        }
        val filterResults = FilterResults()
        filterResults.values = filteredList
        return filterResults
    }

    override fun publishResults(
        charSequence: CharSequence,
        filterResults: FilterResults
    ) {
        mFilteredItemList.clear()
        mFilteredItemList.addAll(filterResults.values as Collection<твой класс>)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

И после этого просто в методе onTextChanged твоего TextWatcher вызывай
`adapter.filter.filter(s)`

Ах, да, не забудь унаследоваться от Filterable в твоем адаптере

Comment: Спасибо за старания, большое спасибо. Но я пишу не  с фильтром, а через sql оператор LIKE, поэтому в самом фильтре просто нету нужды.